# Separar nome do ramal - em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Tenho uma coluna na planilha em Excel com a seguinte coluna:

```
Atendido por 
Ismael  (100)
JEFFERSON LUIZ ESTEVAO DE MOURA (111)
Felipe Braga Regis Souza (222)
```

Tenho que pegar apenas o nome e colocar em uma nova coluna e o ramal em outra, se o exemplo abaixo:

```
ANALISTA                                         RAMAL

Ismael                                           100
JEFFERSON LUIZ ESTEVAO DE MOURA                  111
Felipe Braga Regis Souza                         222
```

Meu código:

```
arquivoxlsx = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Desktop/Python/Base/Atendidas.xlsx')

Atendidapor = arquivoxlsx["Atendida por"]
cont = 0
indice = 0

for c in Atendidapor:
    Analista = arquivoxlsx.at[cont,'Atendida por']
    tamanhomatriz = len(Analista.split())


    # print(registro)


    while True:
        registro = Atendidapor.get(indice)
        if indice < tamanhomatriz:
            arquivoxlsx.at[cont, 'Analista'] = registro + ""
        else:
            arquivoxlsx.at[cont, 'Analista'] = "" + registro
            indice = 0
            break
        indice  += 1
    #
    cont += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Consegues extrair os valores diretamente através dos métodos [extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) e [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) das [Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) do Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

data = ['Ismael  (100)', 'JEFFERSON LUIZ ESTEVAO DE MOURA (111)', 'Felipe Braga Regis Souza (222)']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Atendido por'])
df['Analista'] = df['Atendido por'].str.replace(r"\((.*)\)", "")
df['Ramal'] = df['Atendido por'].str.extract(r"\((.*)\)")
df.drop(df.columns[[0]], axis=1, inplace=True)

Out[3]:
                           Analista Ramal
0                          Ismael     100
1  JEFFERSON LUIZ ESTEVAO DE MOURA    111
2         Felipe Braga Regis Souza    222
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o split pelo parentese assim você vai ter uma lista onde o primeiro elemento será o nome e o segundo elemento o número com os parenteses depois é só você incluir cada valor na sua devida coluna.

```
   for x in Atendidapor.index:
        lista = Atendidapor[x].split("(")
        arquivoxlsx['ANALISTA'][x] = lista[0]
        arquivoxlsx['RAMAL'][x] = lista[1].replace("(", "").replace(")", "")
```